# UDP receive callback function wont execute . Why?

Tags: c, timer, udp, stm32, lwip

```
int main(void)
{
  
  HAL_Init();

  
  SystemClock_Config();

  
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_LWIP_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  struct udp_pcb* Demo_upcb;
  ip_addr_t myIPADDR,destip;
  IP_ADDR4(&myIPADDR,192,168,33,1);
  IP_ADDR4(&destip,192,168,33,101);

  Demo_upcb = udp_new();
  err_t er3 = udp_bind(Demo_upcb, &myIPADDR, 8);
  if(er3 != ERR_OK)
      {
          while(1)
                  {
                      HAL_Delay(200);
                      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD3_GPIO_Port, LD3_Pin);
                  }
      }
      sprintf(buffer,"This is UDP message\r\n");

      struct pbuf* psend = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, 30, PBUF_RAM);

      memcpy(psend->payload, buffer , 30);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim6);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

      ethernetif_input(&gnetif);
              sys_check_timeouts();


  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin);//Blue LED
    udp_recv(Demo_upcb, &udpcall, NULL);
}

void udpcall(void *arg, struct udp_pcb *pcb, struct pbuf *p, const ip_addr_t *addr, u16_t port)
{
    sprintf(buffer,"This is UDP message \r\n ");
          struct pbuf* psend = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, 30, PBUF_RAM);
          memcpy(psend->payload, buffer , 30);
    udp_connect(pcb, addr, port);
    err_t err2 = udp_send(pcb, psend);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LD3_GPIO_Port, LD3_Pin);//Green LED
     pbuf_free(psend);
    pbuf_free(p);
}
```

I am trying to set a UDP connection by sending UDP packets to the stm32 board's ip address through a UDP sender application. In the board I aim to read the UDP packets and at every packet received to send a UDP packet back to my laptop.
I set up the timer to call the HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback every one second. At every one second, the udp_recv() function will be called and before that a Blue LED will blink. I put a blinking LED code in udpcall() function block to know whether the udpcall of function is being processed or not. It seems that the control never enters the udpcall function as the Green LED never blinks.

Can anyone figure out whats wrong, and why it wont execute the udpcall function?

Comment: What happened when you stepped through with your debugger?

Comment: same thing, the control never enters the udpcall function